# Does anyone know any good resources for working as a sign writer / designer?

Tags: resource-recommendations, signage

I currently work for a small but very busy family sign writing business. This includes 4 family members mum, dad and two adult kids :) there are three extra employees including me. My role is the printing and design management and I do heaps of signage which includes vehicles, flags, billboards, printing and design work which includes logo,business cards and poster design. I would really like to find some good forums websites or a network of people who work in the same industry. I enjoy working in signage and just want to keep expanding my knowledge and skills and be a real asset to help there business :)

Comment: I voted to close this as "too broad". Typically "shopping list" questions, or questions which merely ask others to list things, are not favored on Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: I've made it your question into a Community Wiki since @Scott is correct that this doesn't make a good question. But it does deserve info I think as its such a specific niche.

Answer (score 0):

www.signs101.com is a great resource and community for any sign related topics, from production, design, and equipment, to installations and just plain good advice.

Signweb is also another forum you should check out as well.